# Regex preg_split between comma

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Preg Spilit
I'm having a tough time getting this to work. I have a string like:

```
input :
Organizer, Pocket Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF Viewer)
```

```
output :
Organizer 
Pocket Office (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, PDF Viewer)
```

Anyone got any ideas to get Pattern Regex?

Comment: It would be good to include what regex you have tried and did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to split at commas inside parenthesis, you can [(*SKIP)(*F)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) parenthesized stuff:

```
$pattern = '/\([^)]+\)(*SKIP)(*F)|,\s*/';
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iU9dG7/2), [test at eval.in](https://eval.in/420691)

```
$res = preg_split($pattern, $str);
```

Comment: Thank You, the pattern is useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

To split on commas *except* those within brackets, use this regex:

```
,(?![^(]*\))
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/GnzBcgoq4g).

This regex says "a comma whose next bracket character *isn't* a closing one".